# MEAN.js (Angular 1) - Drag & drop functionality stops working after server migration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I've been working on a MEAN.js application that uses ngDrapDrop plugin to move jobs from 1 column to another to indicate progress.
The current (live) app works fine on the server (Ubuntu) its on, but when that app is replicated on my local dev environment (macOS) or onto a staging server (tried multiple) to try move the site away from the old host, some of the drag & drop functionality fails.

Run through of the issue:

- Dragging and dropping an element to another column (works)
- When element dropped, pop-up modals activated on some columns to indicate job progress (works)
- Data entered on the modal is entered into MondoDB asynchronously (works)
- On hitting submit the modal closes, element goes back to the nearest column and data reverts in mongodb (broke) whereas, ngDragDrop typical behaviour is that the element (job) is dropped into the column and the data is still stored in MongoDB.

This behaviour only happens on columns where a modal is present on dropping the job, which suggests that the error is with the modal however the data is saved as expected.
There are no errors that appear in the console either.

I've checked the functions, controllers and models controlling/influencing all those points and can't find anything obvious.

Is there anything I may have missed? Anything that could have an effect moving from different OS's? Any advice appreciated.

Edit: The expected behaviour has been added with extra explanation

Comment: are there any errors that are thrown when this happens either in the browser or in the server console?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the 
shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: There's no console errors - i've added logs to give feedback after jobs are dropped into columns and modal is confirmed. Data just reverts back as if it's expected to do so. The only difference I can think is the OS and potentially some packages, but surely this behaviour isn't expected when moving from Ubuntu to CentOS?

Comment: Improved explanation added also - thanks for pointing out